# Polymorphic relationships in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, entity-relationship

I got a questions which I am trying to solve on my own for hours and hours but I do not find a proper solution - so I need your combined brain power ;)

I have a game-management Laravel app which should offer a generic messaging system for the following entities:

- Character
- Villain

Each user can have a unknown number of characters and villains.

The messaging system should connect every entity with each other, that means connections could be as following:

- Character --> Character
- Character --> Villain
- Villain --> Character
- Villain --> Villain

Obviously Characters and Villains are different eloquent models in Laravel.

For a better overview I'd like to develop a message inbox, like a webmailer, that shows all messages from all characters and villains combined.

My idea was to create polymorphic one-to-many relationship and add two morphs to the message model:

```
public function sender ()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function recipient ()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

While the character and the villain model also have two morphs, each like:

```
public function receivedMessages()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Message', 'recipient');
}

public function sentMessages()
{
    return $this->morphMany('App\Models\Message', 'sender');
}
```

My messages table contains the required field for polymorph relationships, created during the migration with using:

```
$table->morphs('sender');
$table->morphs('recipient');
```

So in my idea I could simply query all messages for a specific user, which would include all character and all villain messages. From that list of messages I should be able to retrieve the individual Character and Villain information, just like that:

```
@foreach($receivedMessages as $message)

    @if($message->sender() instanceof \App\Models\Character)
        // Do something character specific
    @endif

    @if($message->sender() instanceof \App\Models\Villain)
        // Do something villain specific
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Unfortunately it seems that I am unable to retrieve neither the character nor the villain information from the message objects. If I just use:

```
$message->sender
```

The result is *null*. If I use:

```
$message->sender()
```

The result is not null, but I am still unable to retrieve the properties of a character or villain instance, e.g.:

```
$message->sender()->name
```

Would always throw an BadMethodCallException.

Any ideas where I am getting it wrong? I no longer see the wood for the trees I fear.

Any help or input is much appreciated!

Thanks everyone,
Jules

Comment: have you created the field with a name following he laravel convention?

Comment: Hi @AlbertoSinigaglia, yes I did indeed. I added the fields senderable_id and _type as well as recipientable_id and _type to my messages table and seeded them accordingly for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I came up with a solution.

By default when you access eloquent relationships as properties, the data of the relationship is lazy loaded. That means it is not loaded by default.

I expected this to behave like a common lazy loading, meaning when I access the property it will automatically load the relationship and give me access to the properties of the related model. This does not seems to be the case.

All I did above works perfectly, once I add the following line to my "Message" eloquent model:

```
protected $with = ['sender', 'recipient'];
```

The protected "with" property of a model tells eloquent which relationships it should eager load (instead of lazy load) when querying for data. With adding sender and recipient, all my related data is loaded by default - not lazy anymore - but it is loaded.

It seems to me that this behaviour might be a bug in Laravel 6.7.0 and I will report this in the GitHub repo.

More information on eager loading can be found here: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Hope that helps.